# tfidfvectorizer prints results based on all words

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, tf-idf

Though there are six different words. There are only 5 words printed in the result. How to get result based on all words  (6 columns vector)?

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
sent=["This is a sample", "This is another example"]
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,1), min_df = 0)
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(sent)
print tfidf_matrix.toarray()
```

> [[ 0.          0.          0.50154891  0.70490949  0.50154891]  [
>   0.57615236  0.57615236  0.40993715  0.          0.40993715]]

Also how to print the column details (features (words)) and row (document) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the default token_pattern, which only selects tokens of 2 or more char.

> token_pattern :
>
> “token”, only used if analyzer == 'word'. The default regexp selects
>   tokens of 2 or more alphanumeric characters (punctuation is completely
>   ignored and always treated as a token separator)

If you define a new token_pattern, you will get the 'a' character, e.g.:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
sent=["This is a sample", "This is another example"]
tf = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?u)\\b\\w+\\b')
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(sent)
print tfidf_matrix.toarray()
tf.vocabulary_
```

[[ 0.57615236  0.          0.          0.40993715  0.57615236  0.40993715]
 [ 0.          0.57615236  0.57615236  0.40993715  0.          0.40993715]]

```
tf.vocabulary_
```

{u'a': 0, u'sample': 4, u'another': 1, u'this': 5, u'is': 3, u'example': 2}